# use of Django-gTTS to say multiple text in one audio

Tags: django, text-to-speech, google-text-to-speech, gtts

I am building a simple quiz app and I am using Django-gTTS to read out some text on my webpage but the problem that I am having is I cannot join regular text and text from my views in one audio tag. For example, I want my code to be something like this:

```
<audio
    src="{% say 'en-us' 'Course name' test.course_name 'Total Marks' total_marks %}"
    controls
></audio>
```

although this exact code will give an error.

Is there any way I can implement this?